# Filter dataset by values IF column contains certain string

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Car = c("Mazda", "Mazda", "Mazda", "Mazda", "Mazda", 
"Mazda", "Lexus"), Date = c("2/20/20", "2/21/20", "2/22/20", 
"2/23/20", "2/24/20", "2/25/20", "9/3/20")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I would only like to filter the Dates where the `Car=="Mazda"`.

In this scenerio, I would like to remove the rows for Mazda cars if the date range is not between 2/20/20 - 2/23/20.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `filter` with `between` from `dplyr` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(Car == 'Mazda' & between(Date, '2/20/20', '2/23/20'))
#>     Car    Date
#> 1 Mazda 2/20/20
#> 2 Mazda 2/21/20
#> 3 Mazda 2/22/20
#> 4 Mazda 2/23/20
```

---

You could use not `!` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(!(Car == 'Mazda' & !between(Date, '2/20/20', '2/23/20')))
#>     Car    Date
#> 1 Mazda 2/20/20
#> 2 Mazda 2/21/20
#> 3 Mazda 2/22/20
#> 4 Mazda 2/23/20
#> 5 Lexus  9/3/20
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to keep the row with the Lexus observation

Comment: Hi @Jamie, You could use not for this, please check updated answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `data.frame`indexing if you dont want to use packages:

```
df$Date = as.Date(strptime(paste0(data$Date,"20"),"%m/%d/%Y"))

df$Date[data$Car=="Mazda"]

mazdaData = df[data$Car=="Mazda",]

mazdaTimeData = df[data$Car=="Mazda"&
                   data$Date<as.Date("2020-02-23")& 
                   data$Date>as.Date("2020-02-20"),]
```

Also I would suggest to assign a date format which conatins the whole year. This would be easier to understand for other programs.